# Why do I see String : null in the output instead of ambiguity or Object : null?

Tags: java, overloading

I am using below code to check which overloaded method will be called.
Why do I see String : null in the output instead of  ambiguity or Object : null?

```
public class Employee {

    public void display(Object o){
        System.out.println("Object : "+ o);
    }
    public void display(String s){
        System.out.println("String : " + s);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        employee.display(null);
    }

}
```

Comment: The Java selection rules for overloaded methods choose the most specific type for null. And the most specific type here is `String`, not `Object`.

Comment: **tl;dr** for the dupe: because the rules say to use the "most specific" version of the method that's applicable. And `String` is more specific than `Object`.

Comment: From [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5): "The informal intuition is that one method is more specific than another if any invocation handled by the first method could be passed on to the other one without a compile-time error." Any String can be passed to either the String or Object overload, but some Objects cannot be passed to the String overload: thus, `display(String)` is more specific.

Comment: If you changed `display(Object o)` to `display(Integer i)`, then the compiler would emit an error, because between `Integer` and `String`, there no most specific type, as neither is a subclass of the other.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. Really appreciate the help.